# How to find the Perl code referenced by this line?

Tags: perl

I have inherited some Perl code which contains a line that is mysterious to me:

```
my $binary = A->current->config->settings('arg1', 'arg2')
```

Basically, I am not sure how to find the related code. "A" is NOT a variable in the local code so I thought this was a class hierarchy. However I checked the directory structure to see if the following path existed, but there was none:

```
A/current/config/settings.pm
```

Is `A->current->config->settings` guaranteed to be a nested class hierarchy, or could it be something else? For example could `config` actually be a property or method of a different object `A->current`?

Any assistance you could lend tracking this down would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`A` is a class name, you should find it in `A.pm`. `current` should be a method of the class, defined under a `sub current` in `A.pm`. It returns an object whose `config` method is being called which returns an object again whose `settings` method is being called with arguments `'arg1'` and `'arg2'` (well, in fact, the object itself is the first argument).

In fact, any of the methods can return a class instead of an object, too.

Answer (score 2):

Step through the code in the [perl debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldebug) and see where it takes you.

`foo->bar` is a method call, meaning that there is likely a subroutine called `bar` defined in the package referred to by `foo` (or a superclass), and gives you no information about whether there is a package `bar` or `foo::bar`.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is `A->current->config->settings` guaranteed to be a nested class hierarchy*

You're thinking of `A::current::config::settings`.

The following are method calls:

```
INVOCANT->name
INVOCANT->name(LIST)
```

That means that `A->current->config->settings` is a chain of method calls.

The only class named in that code is `A`.

> *could `config` actually be a property or method of a different object `A->current`?*

It's the name of a method of the object or class returned by `A->current`.

> *How to find the Perl code referenced by this line?*

```
my $binary = A->current->config->settings('arg1', 'arg2');
```

is short for

```
my $obj1   = A->current;
my $obj2   = $obj1->config;
my $binary = $obj2->settings('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Now that you have the objects available, you can find the class of which they are an instance using

```
say ref($obj) || "Not a reference";
```

or

```
use Scalar::Util qw( blessed );

say blessed($obj) // "Not an object";
```

Comment: What's confusing to me, though, is that there is no sigil in front of A. If we are saying that A->current is an object, shouldn't there be a $ at the beginning of A?

Comment: Barewords on the left-hand side of `->` will be auto stringifird. So `A->method` is the same as `"A"->method` (unless a sub called `A` exists)

Comment: They are auto-stringified, yes, but that isn't the same thing as not needing a sigil, is it?

Comment: I meant auto-quoted. See the example I provided again.

Comment: Let me ask a different question in that case: Do we know if A (alone, without the ->current) is a class or an object?

Comment: Without context, we can't tell. `A` could evaluate to a number of things, including (but not limited to) an object or a string (class name). Even if it's followed by `->`

Answer (score 2):

As explained, you are dealing with a chain of method calls in the class named `A`, where at least the first one is a [class method](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation) since it is invoked on the class (`A`) itself, not on an object.

An easy way to find that class is by using [Class::Inspector](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-Inspector/lib/Class/Inspector.pm)

```
use Class::Inspector;

say "Filename: ", Class::Inspector->resolved_filename( 'A' );
```

which printed the full path to the class I used in my tests.  Also see `loaded_filename`.

---

Another interesting way to interrogate a class is to add to it at runtime.

Create an object of `A` and add to it a method of your choice at runtime

```
my $objA = A->new();

eval q( sub A::get_info { print "$_\n" for (caller(0)) } );    
if ($@) { print "Eval: $@" };

eval q( sub A::boom { croak "Stacktrace: " } );
if ($@) { print "Eval: $@" };

$objA->get_info();

$objA->boom();
```

These are simple examples but you can acquire practically any information from inside a method.

If `A` happens to not have a method called `new` (possible) work with methods in the given chain, starting with `my $objA = A->current`.

Or, you can directly add a subroutine to the package's symbol table

```
*{A::new_method} = sub { say "A new method" };

$any_obj_of_A->new_method();
```

which is now also available on all existing instances, as well as on new ones.